# "ERROR: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt" for openssl 1.1.1h but works in 1.1.1b

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl, php-7.3

I have a third party app that sends an encrypted data file and I can decrypt it locally using openssl 1.1.1b but not in production using openssl 1.1.1h although this maybe a red herring and it might be a certificate or other configuration issue but has anyone else seen this before?  This is the function I am using that is failing with the EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt error being displayed.

```
    {
       $secret_key = '???';      
       $secret_iv ='???';
       $key = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_key, true), 0, 32);                 
       $output =openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($content),'aes-256-cbc', $key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$secret_iv);
       if (!$output) 
         {
            while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
            {
               echo "<br>ERROR: " . $msg;
            }
         }
        return $output ;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check that the "content" is identical on production and locally (e.g. by sha-256 hashing)? You didn't show the file reading function that could cause the problem because of different default encodings on local and production system.